# How can I better handle binary ReST resource errors when submitting a form to download those resources?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I have a service that generates a PDF document via a form of which `GET`s a ReST resource based on the input parameters. Some of these entries map to request path's and others map to optional request arguments such that the following illustrates the ReST resource.

```
/api/invoices/{invoiceNumber}?format={format}
```

On form submission I rewrite the `action` on the `form` to match the resource URI. But if the invoice number does not exist the resource will return `404` or any other error code required based on any error condition.

I can fix this instead by setting an error message on the page, but as the forms `target` is `_blank` to open a new window the form is redisplayed in the target window with the correct error message but of course the form is blank.

I would rather prefer the document was handled via an asynchronous ajax request that could detect and handle any error messages/conditions appropriately but I'm not sure if this is possible (with jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to conditionally open the window because you will have already downloaded the content into the parent window at that point.  This may be possible using JQuery but typically sending content between windows is troublesome and fragile.

What I would do instead is on form submit

- open a new window with an alternate action, e.g., fileShowAction, with your restful URL passed as a parameter
- have the new window submit the URL via JQuery or as another form
- if there's an error you can show an error with OK or timer to close the window

**Option 2**

Show the file in a JQuery inline dialog with an IFrame

**Option 3**

Have your initial REST call either return HTML with errors, etc., or a redirect to the file location. There are also several other alternatives using the semantics of REST e.g., using a `Location` header.